# How can I pass generic type to generic methode?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class which is some thing  like below

```
//Un modifiable source 
public AbstractJsonWebserviceConnector<T extends JsonRequest, U>{
    public U getResponse(T request, Class<U> responseType) throws Exception {
        //Do Some stuff
    }       
}
```

Another class extends it as below

```
public class GenericConnector<T> extends AbstractJsonWebserviceConnector<JsonRequest, T> {
   public T process(JsonRequest request, Class<T> tClass) throws Exception {
        return this.getResponse(request, tClass);
    }
}
```

MCan I convert it to something like below for avoiding the extra parameter Class<T> tClass ?

```
public class GenericConnector<T> extends AbstractJsonWebserviceConnector<JsonRequest, T> {
   public T process(JsonRequest request) throws Exception {
        return this.getResponse(request, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you just want to change the signature of process method. As it can have one parameter or multiple, please confirm

Comment: Yes, I want to know if I can change the signature of method process so that I can avoid the extra parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a trick for it, although it's ugly.

```
public class GenericConnector<T> extends AbstractJsonWebserviceConnector<JsonRequest, T> {
   public T process(JsonRequest request) throws Exception {
        return this.getResponse(request, (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public T process(JsonRequest request, Class... tClass), this will support none or one object for Class

Comment: Please note that the method getResponse requires both parameters. So varargs is not a solution

Comment: you can send any object and in the response method you should accept an object parameter, then using inistanceof or what ever as per your need you can continue the processing

Comment: I'm Sorry, I couldn't understand your suggestion. Could you please provide some example?

Comment: public T process(JsonRequest request, Class<T>... tClass),

return this.getResponse(request, typeof(T));

//Declaration of getResponse
getResponse (JsonRequest request, Object... tClass){

if(tClass instanceof xxx)
// add your logic

}

hope this is what you want

Comment: As noted  in the question the method getResponse is unmodifiable. Also introducing dependency with all the possible classes in side the if-else is not practical.

Comment: can you please share signature of getResponse method

Comment: public U getResponse(T , Class<U> ) throws Exception